# Cassandra retry_policy is not enforced in python client?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

1. I have a single node Apache Cassandra cluster 3.11.6
2. I write 2750 rows by 10000 columns each first in apache airflow DAG task (this is successfully passed)
3. Then immediately after I try to connect to Cassandra to perform various reads inside another set of parallel tasks of the same airflow DAG and it fails with
   `ERROR - ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'10.0.1.135:9042': OperationTimedOut('errors=None, last_host=None')})`
4. I have configured retries in `execution_profiles`, but it seems they're **not** enforced or I am misreading how the "retry" is supposed to work on the client side.
5. `nodetool status` shows UN, means UP/Normal.
6. I have multiple DAG tasks running in parallel pulling info from Cassandra. Some of them finish successfully (green), but some do fail because of the OperationTimedOut exception.

I don't get retries with failed connections, you can see this in the following apache airflow log:

- it **started** at [2020-07-22 22:16:28,345]
- and it **errored** at [2020-07-22 22:16:31,546]

which is just 3 seconds. However in the profile I set:

```py
retry_policy=ConstantReconnectionPolicy(delay=10),
```

#### Log

```
[2020-07-22 22:16:28,345] {{taskinstance.py:880}} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2020-07-22 22:16:28,345] {{taskinstance.py:881}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-07-22 22:16:28,359] {{taskinstance.py:900}} INFO - Executing <Task(DjangoOperator): RespondentMediaValueMatrixImportStep> on 2020-07-22T22:02:20+00:00
[2020-07-22 22:16:28,363] {{standard_task_runner.py:53}} INFO - Started process 651 to run task
[2020-07-22 22:16:28,622] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: etl-run-dag.RespondentMediaValueMatrixImportStep 2020-07-22T22:02:20+00:00 [running]> 10.0.102.143
[2020-07-22 22:16:28,803] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2020-07-22 22:16:28,802] {{connection.py:101}} WARNING - Cluster.__init__ called with contact_points specified, but load-balancing policies are not specified in some ExecutionProfiles. In the next major version, this will raise an error; please specify a load-balancing policy. (contact_points = ['cassandra-node0.dev.emotionaldna.host'], EPs without explicit LBPs = ('EXEC_PROFILE_DEFAULT',))
[2020-07-22 22:16:29,543] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2020-07-22 22:16:29,543] {{policies.py:292}} INFO - Using datacenter 'us-east-2' for DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy (via host '10.0.1.135:9042'); if incorrect, please specify a local_dc to the constructor, or limit contact points to local cluster nodes
[2020-07-22 22:16:31,545] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2020-07-22 22:16:31,545] {{connection.py:103}} WARNING - [control connection] Error connecting to 10.0.1.135:9042:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3522, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._reconnect_internal
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3591, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._try_connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3588, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._try_connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3690, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._refresh_schema
  File "cassandra/metadata.py", line 142, in cassandra.metadata.Metadata.refresh
  File "cassandra/metadata.py", line 165, in cassandra.metadata.Metadata._rebuild_all
  File "cassandra/metadata.py", line 2522, in get_all_keyspaces
  File "cassandra/metadata.py", line 2031, in get_all_keyspaces
  File "cassandra/metadata.py", line 2719, in cassandra.metadata.SchemaParserV3._query_all
  File "cassandra/connection.py", line 985, in cassandra.connection.Connection.wait_for_responses
  File "cassandra/connection.py", line 983, in cassandra.connection.Connection.wait_for_responses
  File "cassandra/connection.py", line 1435, in cassandra.connection.ResponseWaiter.deliver
cassandra.OperationTimedOut: errors=None, last_host=None
[2020-07-22 22:16:31,546] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2020-07-22 22:16:31,545] {{connection.py:103}} ERROR - Control connection failed to connect, shutting down Cluster:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1690, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3488, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection.connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3533, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._reconnect_internal
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'10.0.1.135:9042': OperationTimedOut('errors=None, last_host=None')})
[2020-07-22 22:16:31,546] {{logging_mixin.py:112}} INFO - [2020-07-22 22:16:31,546] {{connection.py:107}} WARNING - [Connection: default] connect failed, setting up for re-attempt on first use
[2020-07-22 22:16:31,546] {{taskinstance.py:1145}} ERROR - ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'10.0.1.135:9042': OperationTimedOut('errors=None, last_host=None')})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 978, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 118, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/app/dags/etl/workflow.py", line 126, in run_import_step
    keyspace=task_instance.get('cassandra_keyspace')
  File "/app/etl_process/import_steps/mixins.py", line 469, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/etl_process/import_steps/mixins.py", line 268, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/etl_process/import_steps/abstract.py", line 177, in __init__
    self._cas = get_session()
  File "/app/etl_process/cassandra/client.py", line 60, in get_session
    execution_profiles={EXEC_PROFILE_DEFAULT: profile},
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/connection.py", line 326, in setup
    retry_connect=retry_connect, cluster_options=kwargs, default=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/connection.py", line 195, in register_connection
    conn.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cassandra/cqlengine/connection.py", line 103, in setup
    self.session = self.cluster.connect()
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1667, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1703, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 1690, in cassandra.cluster.Cluster.connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3488, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection.connect
  File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 3533, in cassandra.cluster.ControlConnection._reconnect_internal
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'10.0.1.135:9042': OperationTimedOut('errors=None, last_host=None')})
```

#### settings.CASSANDRA is

```
CASSANDRA_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 90000

CASSANDRA = {
        'NAME': 'cassandra',
        'USER': user,
        'PASSWORD': password,
        'TEST_NAME': 'test_db',
        'HOST': host,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'replication': {
                'strategy_class': 'SimpleStrategy',
                'replication_factor': 1,
            },
            'connection': {
                'consistency': CASSANDRA_CONSISTENCY_LEVEL,
                'retry_connect': True,
            },
            'session': {
                'default_timeout': CASSANDRA_REQUEST_TIMEOUT,
                'default_fetch_size': 10000,
            },
        },
    }
```

#### get_session()

```py
from django.conf import settings

from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
from cassandra.cluster import EXEC_PROFILE_DEFAULT, ExecutionProfile
from cassandra.cqlengine import connection
from cassandra.policies import (
    ConstantReconnectionPolicy, DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy
)
from cassandra.query import tuple_factory

__all__ = ['get_session']


def get_session(
    keyspace: str = None,
    consistency_level=settings.CASSANDRA_CONSISTENCY_LEVEL,
    request_timeout=settings.CASSANDRA_REQUEST_TIMEOUT,
) -> connection:
    """Initiate connection with apache cassandra cluster.

    Arguments:
    :param str keyspace: default keyspace to connect to
    :param int consistency_level: desired consistency level of the connection
    :param int request_timeout: cassandra request timeout. If wait time exceeds
        this number, then cassandra will send 1300 error code with 0 nodes
        replied statement in the response.

    """

    dbconf = settings.CASSANDRA

    auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(
        username=dbconf['USER'],
        password=dbconf['PASSWORD'],
    )

    host = dbconf['HOST']

    # define execution profile for the cluster/session
    profile = ExecutionProfile(
        retry_policy=ConstantReconnectionPolicy(delay=10),
        consistency_level=consistency_level,
        request_timeout=request_timeout,
        row_factory=tuple_factory
    )

    # the host should be always LIST passed in the connection
    # setup
    if isinstance(host, str):
        host = [host]

    # setup the connection
    connection.setup(
        host,
        keyspace,
        retry_connect=True,
        protocol_version=4,
        auth_provider=auth_provider,
        consistency=consistency_level,
        execution_profiles={EXEC_PROFILE_DEFAULT: profile},
    )

    return connection.session
```

#### cassandra.yaml

```
# How long the coordinator should wait for read operations to complete
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 600000
# How long the coordinator should wait for seq or index scans to complete
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 600000
# How long the coordinator should wait for writes to complete
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 600000
# How long the coordinator should wait for counter writes to complete
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 100000
# How long a coordinator should continue to retry a CAS operation
# that contends with other proposals for the same row
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 100000
# How long the coordinator should wait for truncates to complete
# (This can be much longer, because unless auto_snapshot is disabled
# we need to flush first so we can snapshot before removing the data.)
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 600000
# The default timeout for other, miscellaneous operations
request_timeout_in_ms: 600000

# How long before a node logs slow queries. Select queries that take longer than
# this timeout to execute, will generate an aggregated log message, so that slow queries
# can be identified. Set this value to zero to disable slow query logging.
slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms: 3000

# Enable operation timeout information exchange between nodes to accurately
# measure request timeouts.  If disabled, replicas will assume that requests
# were forwarded to them instantly by the coordinator, which means that
# under overload conditions we will waste that much extra time processing 
# already-timed-out requests.
#
# Warning: before enabling this property make sure to ntp is installed
# and the times are synchronized between the nodes.
cross_node_timeout: false
```

Comment: can you also show how you insert data?

Comment: are you using batches for inserting data?

Comment: @AlexOtt yes I am using batches to insert data. Insert step pass without any issues.

Comment: @AlexOtt see how I use batches in writes
https://gist.github.com/githubsaritasa/b2704b41ace702a4267f8bb89e2ff935

Comment: Please don’t do that - batches in Cassandra is different from batches in RDBMS - by doing it, you’re really harming performance of your job. Better solution - async queries in parallel.

Comment: Also. Query prepare should be outside of the rows loop...

Answer (score 1):

You're using incorrect class as parameter for `retry_policy`.  What you're specifying is [reconnection policy](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.24/api/cassandra/policies/#reconnecting-to-dead-hosts) that defines how to try to re-connect to the node that is marked as `DOWN`.  Retry policy defines what to do with failed statements.  And you can omit it, as by default it's set to the [RetryPolicy class](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.24/api/cassandra/cluster/#cassandra.cluster.Cluster.default_retry_policy) that may retry some statements, but only if they are marked as `is_idempotent=True` (see [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.24/api/cassandra/query/))

Comment: I have noticed that later too and changed it - but again it brought no effect.
https://gist.github.com/githubsaritasa/c2e37342fffe8c5158272fdea0a35047

Comment: to retry statement it needs to be marked as idempotent...